# Jetty webserver after idle breaks

Tags: spring, jsf, webserver, jetty

I have a webapp deployed successfully in Jetty webserver.
The webserver responds to requests fine.
When I access the app it renders the home page.
Recently I noticed that when I don't use the app for certain period of time it breaks somehow. The period is somewhere around 2/3 weeks.
When I access the webapp after 2/3 weeks of idle I receive [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JgXT.png) output.
If I try to access any other link, i.e. the login page (/login.faces) I receive:

> Problem accessing /error/not-found.faces.  Reason:
>   /error/not-found.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

which normally used to work before idling.
If I restart the webserver everything returns to normal and works fine. There are scheduled tasks set which make the app interact every day with database. (There is a scheduled task for fetching currency rates via webservice).

Therefore, my question is what would be the cause which breaks the site and makes it unavailable after idling? Is this a webserver (jetty) issue? Am I missing any setting which is crucial?

FYI, the project structure is: Java with Spring, Hibernate, JSF (PrimeFaces) and Jetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred due to permissions in CentOS.
If anyone faces the same issue make sure to check the logs have appropriate permissions to read and write